# Can I use cookies or can't I use cookies?

Tags: cookies

I need to use cookies for user site usage information, not so much credentials. It's mostly a backup for a JavaScript object storage mechanism for what the user does on the site. Nothing to do with logins or authentication (no login feature).

Is this okay? I'm not based in EU. The site is deployed in the Philippines though I am based in the US.

I don't know why I'm concerned about this, as I don't seem to have a problem slapping Google Analytics on websites and that uses the client's cookies.

Comment: There's no law in EU or outside of it that makes cookies illegal.

Comment: I mean I start seeing these websites that say "Do you accept/allow us to use cookies on your site" and that prompted me to search and I saw that stuff about EU. This is good news though, one of those things that you can be concerned about but easily overlook like people modifying social media site logos although the site says "do not modify"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do it comply with the `Cookie Law`. Basically you have to

> "to get consent from visitors to store or retrieve any information on
>   a computer, smartphone or tablet." (https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/)

You have to follow this law, since you probably want EU users to be able to access your site.

> "All websites owned in the EU or targeted towards EU citizens, are now
>   expected to comply with the law."
>   (https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/)

**Further Reading**
https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/

Comment: Probably doesn't make sense to ask you haha (go Google it for myself) but what about detecting if an IP is coming from EU, geoip or I realize proxies too, vpns... but ahhh what a hassle, I've only seen these cookie notifications on a few sites. I wonder if even stack exchange/overflow does this.

Comment: @JacobDavidC.Cunningham It would be way easier just prompt everyone, but if you want just EU, then grab their ip (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php) then use this api: http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Comment: I still don't get the whole prompting thing when not a lot of sites do it, also you can see in the browser what the cookies are. It's like is Google Analytics just not going to work unless they agree? edit: granted I use uBlock/Adblock and it's possible it's not even available... still one of those "it's a nice idea" like designing with accessibility when the majority of your traffic is 95% not affected by those problems.